# sql NOT LIKE NULL

Tags: sql

In my where clause,
I have the following:

```
   where SharePt  NOT LIKE 'SharePoint Document%'
```

The result does not return anything even though SharePt is null.

But when I do the following it works 
OR SharePtVer IS NULL

```
    where SharePt  NOT LIKE 'SharePoint Document%' OR SharePt  IS NULL
```

Wondering why NOT LIKE doesn't work in terms of including a NULL>

Comment: FYI ... if you want to avoid remembering precedence, parentheses, etc., as you would using an OR (`WHERE SharePt NOT LIKE 'SharePoint Document%' OR SharePt IS NULL`), you can use the `COALESCE()` function instead: `WHERE COALESCE(SharePt, '') NOT LIKE 'SharePoint Document%'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL uses [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)... `NULL` is not the same as `FALSE`, and `NOT NULL` is not the same as `TRUE`.

`NULL` represents the absence of a value, and functions an unknown value in SQL's three valued logic:

```
A AND B | TRUE    | FALSE   | Unknown
--------+---------+---------+--------
TRUE    | TRUE    | FALSE   | Unknown
FALSE   | FALSE   | FALSE   | FALSE
Unknown | Unknown | FALSE   | Unknown


A OR B  | True    | False   | Unknown
--------+---------+---------+--------
True    | True    | True    | True
False   | True    | False   | Unknown
Unknown | True    | Unknown | Unknown
```

When `where SharePt  NOT LIKE 'SharePoint Document%'` is evaluated, if `SharePt` is `NULL`, or unknown... then the result would be unknown... `SharePt` may or may not be `LIKE 'SharePoint Document%'`.

Comment: ...feel free to grab the tables from my answer :)

Comment: @onedaywhen Thanks, you're right about `null` not being a value... I've updated my answer to correct this.  When I say that it functions as an unknown value, I'm relating unknown to `null` in the truth tables.

Answer (score 3):

The full truth tables in Michael Fredrickson answers should be as follows:

```
    A    |    B    | A AND B
---------+---------+--------
  TRUE   |  TRUE   |  TRUE  
  TRUE   | UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN
  TRUE   |  FALSE  |  FALSE 
  FALSE  |  TRUE   |  FALSE 
  FALSE  | UNKNOWN |  FALSE 
  FALSE  |  FALSE  |  FALSE 
 UNKNOWN |  TRUE   | UNKNOWN
 UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN
 UNKNOWN |  FALSE  |  FALSE 

    A    |    B    | A OR B
---------+---------+-------
  TRUE   |  TRUE   |  TRUE  
  TRUE   | UNKNOWN |  TRUE  
  TRUE   |  FALSE  |  TRUE  
  FALSE  |  TRUE   |  TRUE  
  FALSE  | UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN
  FALSE  |  FALSE  |  FALSE 
 UNKNOWN |  TRUE   |  TRUE  
 UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN
 UNKNOWN |  FALSE  | UNKNOWN
```

The OP's predicates:

```
( SharePt NOT LIKE 'SharePoint Document%' ) OR ( SharePt IS NULL )
```

Using `NULL` for the variable `SharePt`:

```
( NULL NOT LIKE 'SharePoint Document%' )  -- evaluates UNKNOWN
( NULL IS NULL )                          -- evaluates to TRUE
```

From the truth tables:

```
( UNKNOWN ) OR ( TRUE )  -- evaluates TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Because unless you're specifcially testing for IS NULL or IS NOT NULL, NULL compared to ANYTHING is NULL/FALSE.

Surprisingly, NULL = NULL is also FALSE

Comment: `NULL =NULL` is **not** false. It is `UNKNOWN`. If it was false then `NOT(NULL=NULL)` would be true. It isn't.

Comment: The first sentence is also a misstatement!